# Installing libexpat0 instead of libexpat1

Tags: 14.04, apt, package-management, shared-library

I'm trying to run BitWise IM on Ubuntu but every time I run the program I get the following message:

```
./BitWise: error while loading shared libraries: libexpat.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I try to install libexpat but it installs libexpat1 which doesn't seem to help. I also tried using `apt-cache search` and I don't see any libexpat0. How can I install `libexpat.so.0`?

Comment: Which Ubuntu release are you on?

Comment: @heemayl I have 14.04

Comment: There is no package providing `libexpat.so.0` ..you can install `libexpat1-dev` which provides `libexpat1.so.1` and then create a symlink `sudo ln -s /lib/"$(arch)"-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1 /lib/"$(arch)"-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.0` ..should work..

Comment: no luck same message

Comment: Is the package you want to install 64 bit or 32 bit?

Comment: It doesn't specify so I'm guessing 32 http://www.bitwiseim.com/download.php

Comment: Yes, it's 32 bit ..so you need to install 32 bit version of `libexpat1-dev`: `sudo apt-get install libexpat1-dev:i386` and then create the appropriate symlink: `sudo ln -s /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1 /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.0`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no package providing `libexpat.so.0` library but there is `libexpat-dev` package that provides `libexpat.so.1`, so you can install the package and then create a symbolic link.

As the `BitWise` is 32 bit, at first you need to install 32 bit of the `libexpat-dev` package:

```
sudo apt-get install libexpat-dev:i386
```

Now you can create a symbolic link making `libexpat.so.0` as the link name and `libexpat.so.1` as the target:

```
sudo ln -s /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1 /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.0
```

Comment: For [CatDCD](http://www.ks.uiuc.edu/Development/MDTools/catdcd/), supplied with VMD, I had to install `libexpat1` then create a soft link for `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.0` pointing to `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1`.  This is the first command: `sudo apt install libexpat1`  This is the second command: `sudo ln -s /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.0`